# How to make xxx.one.com load content from yyy.two.com

Tags: domain-name-system, hosting

I'm currently in need to have xxx.one.com load the content of yyy.two.com. That means that when someone will enter xxx.one.com they'll actually see the content of yyy.two.com (URL in the browser won't change and will remain xxx.one.com).

The domains are hosted on separate hosting company. yyy.two.com is on a cPanel and xxx.one.com is on an unknown hosting plan, though I can get its details.

yyy.two.com have the same IP of www.two.com and this cannot be changed (as the hosting company told me).

Any ideas on how do I tackle this issue?

Thanks,

Roy

Comment: I take it by "will remain yyy.two.com", you mean "will remain xxx.one.com"?

Answer (score 5):

Can you change the DNS record for xxx.one.com be a CNAME to yyy.two.com? You'll also need to configure the web server of yyy.two.com to treat xxx.one.com as a alias (ServerAlias in Apache speak)

Comment: I can create CNAME, yea. But are you sure that yyy.two.com to treat xxx.one.com as an alias and not the other way around?

Comment: I agree with the CNAME or Host suggestion.  Just send the original request to the correct host up front by using DNS.  By far the easiest. Otherwise you'll need to proxy it, which is possible but requires more than a shared account through a hosting company.

Comment: Do I need either sub domains to have a dedicated IP, separate from the root domain in order to implement this?

Comment: No, they can be on an IP that is also used for other virtual hosts.

Answer (score 1):

How about an old school iframe?

Your browser does not support iframes.

Comment: Not good for other technical reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use proxypass and proxyreverse.

Reverse Proxy example:
ProxyPass /foo http://foo.example.com/bar
ProxyPassReverse /foo http://foo.example.com/bar

More at: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html

**Details:**

If you are using apache you can add a virtual host for xxx.one.com. In that one adding the ProxyPass example as above will make the url at http://xxx.one.com/foo to load the content from foo.example.com/bar.

This example is useful whem you don't want to expose that site directly on the internet or when you are too lazy to modify the vpn for a single website (example can continue).

In a web hosting environment this permited only if you have a VPS machine or if you have acceess to the apache's config file:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass

> Context:  server config, virtual host,
>   directory

Let me know if more details are needed.

Comment: I didn't understand your example. Can you elaborate

Comment: Edited, check now.

Comment: Much better,  thanks. Though it might be a good solution in some cases often the site loading the content will be on a shared hosting package, thus this might not be always applicable.